# CALayer shadowPath ignored on rendering as image

Tags: swift, calayer, nsimage, nsbezierpath, nsshadow

I am making an app that uses CAlayer to show contents like image in a NSWindow. The layer has shadows styled with shadowPath to make a better appearance. Finally to save/export the whole CAlayer and its contents the parent NSView is converted to an NSImage.
The shadow in NSImage is entirely different from that of the actual shadow in CALayer. I can't get the reason why this is happening. Is it a normal thing on AppKit or am I doing it wrong?

These are the difference in shadows:

image(1) - CAlayer with shadowPath (Shadow only in bottom).

image(2) - NSImage created from the superview (Shadow in 4 sides).

[image]

This is how shadow is added in image(1):

```
    layer?.masksToBounds = false
    let size: CGFloat = 100
    let distance: CGFloat = 200
    let rect = CGRect(
        x: -size,
        y: layer.frame.height - (size * 0.4) + distance,
        width: layer.frame.width + size * 2,
        height: size
    )

    layer.shadowColor = .black
    layer.shadowRadius = 100
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowPath = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath
```

This is how the superview is converted to NSImage image(2):

```
    let imageRep = view.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: view.bounds)
    
    view.cacheDisplay(in: view.bounds, to: imageRep!)
    let image = NSImage(size: view.bounds.size)
    image.addRepresentation(imageRep!)
    let imageData = image.tiffRepresentation

    return NSImage(data: imageData!)!
```

Comment: Curious... I am much more familiar with **iOS**, but quick testing confirms your results. Notable, ***the same thing happens on iOS*** when using `render(in ctx: CGContext)` -- however, we ***can*** get the `shadowPath` in the image when using `drawHierarchy(in rect: CGRect, afterScreenUpdates afterUpdates: Bool)`.

Comment: @DonMag You are correct, If we use "drawHierarchy" in iOS it renders shadows and 3Dtransforms but this method is not available in OSX. Any idea to replicate it with some other functions ?

Comment: hmmm... searching hasn't come up with any solutions. Tried a bunch of things including trying to rasterize the layer, adding sublayers, adding subviews, etc... no luck. I'm posting an answer with *one* possible option, although it may not be suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One option - may or may not be suitable:

- generate an oval image
- blur that image
- use the resulting image in an image view or maybe as the content of a layer

Here's an attempt - note: I work with iOS, so lots of hard-coded values and possibly (likely) incorrect ways to do this:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    let cyanView = NSView()
    let shadowView = NSImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.wantsLayer = true
        if let myLayer = view.layer {
            myLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.gray.cgColor
        }
        
        cyanView.wantsLayer = true
        if let myLayer = cyanView.layer {
            myLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.cyan.cgColor
        }
        
        // let's use constraints
        [shadowView, cyanView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            cyanView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400.0),
            cyanView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            cyanView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            cyanView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            
            shadowView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cyanView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.5),
            shadowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            shadowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cyanView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadowView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cyanView.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        let recognizer = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clickView(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayout() {
        super.viewDidLayout()
        
        // create a blurred oval image for the shadowView
        let img = NSImage.init(color: .black, size: shadowView.frame.size).oval()
        
        guard let tiffRep = img.tiffRepresentation,
              let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        else { return }
        let inputImage = CIImage(data: tiffRep)
        blurFilter.setDefaults()
        blurFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: 40.0), forKey: "inputRadius")
        guard let outputImage = blurFilter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage else { return }
        let outputImageRect = NSRectFromCGRect(outputImage.extent)
        let blurredImage = NSImage(size: outputImageRect.size)
        blurredImage.lockFocus()
        outputImage.draw(at: .zero, from: outputImageRect, operation: .copy, fraction: 1.0)
        blurredImage.unlockFocus()
        
        shadowView.image = blurredImage.resize(to: shadowView.bounds.size)
    }
    
    @objc func clickView(_ sender: NSClickGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let img = view.imageRepresentation()
        
        // do something with the image
        
        print("clicked")
        
    }
    
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    
}
extension NSView {
    
    func imageRepresentation() -> NSImage? {
        if let bitRep = self.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: self.bounds) {
            bitRep.size = self.bounds.size
            self.cacheDisplay(in: self.bounds, to: bitRep)
            let image = NSImage(size: self.bounds.size)
            image.addRepresentation(bitRep)
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }

}

extension NSImage {
    
    func resize(to size: NSSize) -> NSImage {
        return NSImage(size: size, flipped: false, drawingHandler: {
            self.draw(in: $0)
            return true
        })
    }

    convenience init(color: NSColor, size: NSSize) {
        self.init(size: size)
        lockFocus()
        color.drawSwatch(in: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        unlockFocus()
    }
    
    func oval(in rect: CGRect) -> NSImage {
        let image = NSImage(size: size)
        image.lockFocus()
        
        NSGraphicsContext.current?.imageInterpolation = .high
        NSBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).addClip()
        draw(at: rect.origin, from: rect, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1)
        
        image.unlockFocus()
        return image
    }
    
    func oval() -> NSImage {
        return oval(in: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    }
    
}
```

Output when running:

[image]

Result of `let img = view.imageRepresentation()`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It will surely work as an alternative solution.